# Wordpress permission problems in centOS

Tags: wordpress, apache, permissions, centos

I've installed wordpress on Centos (apache) and i was having problems to let wordpress automatically perform certain tasks like updating plugins and making changing to theme files in editor. I studied about permissions in wordpress codex and i made changes to the files permission in my /var/www/html directory. I set all the directories to 0775 and all the files for 0664 but the thing is still not working.

I think that it has something to do with the users. I think that wordpress is not set as the appropriate users to do those tasks. Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like it's an issue with ownership rather than permissions.

Login using SSH.

Run the following command:

```
sudo chown apache:apache /var/www/html
```

This changes the ownership of your web root to the web server allowing WordPress to write files (perform automatic updates etc).

Comment: Hello, i think that this solves the problem but can you give me something to let the wordpress built in theme editor to change theme files. i think i need to assign special permissions for that.

Comment: This is the answer. There's no special permissions required for what you're asking.